# write to music directory in android 11

Tags: java, android, audio, file-writing, scoped-storage

My task is to make a really old android app target the latest android version which includes the scoped storage changes introduced in android 11.

The app "had" the working feature to export audio playlists into the external shared storage. After already asking a question it is now clear that my only option probably is to write in the shared music folder so I changed the following:

```
File ext = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File newDir = new File(ext + "/" + "coachyyplayerplaylists");
```

to

```
File ext = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
            File newDir = new File(ext + "/" + "coachyyplayerplaylists");
```

After changing that the folder does get created in the music folder but when trying to write to it nothing happens other than an IOException being thrown.

Here is the full code(Don't mind it I know its really bad):

```
 try {
            File ext = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
            File newDir = new File(ext + "/" + "coachyyplayerplaylists");
            if (!newDir.exists()) {
                newDir.mkdir();
            }
            String name = currentPlaylist.filePath.substring(currentPlaylist.filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            boolean didWriteAll = true;
            String s = "";

            for (Song song : currentPlaylist.getSongs(this)) {
                if (song.title != null && song.title.length() > 0 && song.artist != null && song.artist.length() > 0) {
                    s += (song.title + "\n" + song.artist + "\n" + song.duration + "\n");
                } else {
                    didWriteAll = false;
                }
            }
            if (s.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Fehler beim Export: Nur Songs mit Titel und Artist können exportiert werden.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (!didWriteAll) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Nicht alle Songs wurden exportiert. Nur Songs mit Titel und Artist können exportiert werden.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(ext + "/" + "coachyyplayerplaylists/" + name + ".coachyyplaylist");
                writer.write(s);
                writer.close();

                String[] toBeScannedStr = new String[1];
                toBeScannedStr[0] = ext + "/" + "coachyyplayerplaylists/" + name + ".coachyyplaylist";
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, toBeScannedStr, null, null);
                showMessage("Die Playlist wurde unter " + ext + "/" + "coachyyplayerplaylists/" + name +
                        ".coachyyplaylist gespeichert");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

So the first thing that I wonder is if this approach is even doable and if yes what is wrong with the code above?

The exception that is being thrown is the following:

```
java.io.IOException: write failed: EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
```

Comment: `if (!newDir.exists()) {
               if(! newDir.mkdir()) return;
            }`

Comment: You should use a file name with an allowed music file extension.

Comment: `new FileWriter(ext + "/" + "coachyyplayerplaylists/" + name + ".coachyyplaylist");` Do not build up a complete path again. Use `newDir` and add the rest.

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me an example of what exactly you would change?

Comment: You should change that what i quoted. Using newDir.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix it for me. Am I doing something wrong?

`File ext = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
            File newDir = new File(ext + "/" + "coachyyplayerplaylists");
            if (!newDir.exists()) {
                if (!newDir.mkdir()) {
                    return;
                }
            }
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newDir + "/" + name + ".coachyyplaylist");
                    writer.write(s);
                    writer.close();`

Comment: Repeat: `You should use a file name with an allowed music file extension.`. And post your code in your post. Not unreadable in comments.